# How to check uniqueness but don't discard duplicate in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm not sure if this is possible in Mongoid. I have two models like this.

```
class Tag
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :slug,                :type => String
    field :created_at,          :type => DateTime, :default => Time.now

    belongs_to :product,            :order => :created_at.desc
end

class Product
    include Mongoid::Document

    paginates_per 30

    field :product_id,          type: String
    field :desc,                type: String
    field :created_at,          type: DateTime

    has_many :tag
end
```

It's quite easy to see that a product can have multiple tags. However, I want my product to have the same tags for multiple times as well (to count). Now if I do this

```
Product.create!({tag: [instance_of_tag1, instance_of_tag1]})
```

Product collection will look something like this

```
{
  "product_id" : "some_id",
  "desc"       : "desc",
  "tag"        : [ObjectId("1"), ObjectId(1")]
}
```

But I want to have only one tag in `Tag` collection. Is this possible? Because right now I will get two tags in `Tag` collection

I could do it manually by doing something like this

```
class Product
    include Mongoid::Document

    paginates_per 30

    field :product_id,          type: String
    field :desc,                type: String
    field :created_at,          type: DateTime

    field :tags,                            type: Array
end
```

But then I won't get the benefit of using Mongoid.

Comment: Are you really looking for `(tag, weight)` pairs rather than repeated tags? An `embeds_many :weighted_tags` might make more sense...

Comment: So would that take care of the duplicate and uniqueness as well?

Comment: Actually, I'm really looking for that as well, but I might have more attributes in Tag and I would like to be able to query from Tag collections as well.

Comment: You could have a separate `tags` collection and embed the tags with weights inside `products`. You might have to update the embedded docs whenever `tags` changes but that's the price you pay for giving up JOINs. You'd need some validations on the embedded docs but Mongoid will scope those validations to the containing doc so that should be okay.